# Angular2: template work, but templateUrl not

Tags: javascript, angular, templates

I want to put the html content in files, to be more easy to understand.
I have this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommentService } from '../services/Comment';
import { Comment } from '../class/Comment';

@Component({
  template: '<ul class="comments"><li *ngFor="let comment of Comments_array"><h3>{{comment.text}}</h3><span>{{comment.author}}</span></li></ul>',
  providers: [CommentService]
})

export class CommentsComponent implements OnInit {
    Comments_array: Comment[];

    constructor(private commentService: CommentService) { }

    ngOnInit() { 

        this.commentService.get_all_comments().subscribe(
        (data) => {
            this.Comments_array = data;
            console.log ( this.Comments_array );
        },
        (error) => {
            console.error(<any>error);
        });  

    }
}
```

In this moment, works great, but if I change template in **templateUrl: 'template/comments'**

and template/comments have:

```
<ul class="comments"><li *ngFor="let comment of Comments_array"><h3>{{comment.text}}</h3><span>{{comment.author}}</span></li></ul
```

// same thing..

I get these errors:

```
window.controllers is deprecated. Do not use it for UA detection.nsHeaderInfo.js:412:8
Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.core.umd.js:241:9
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors:
Unexpected character "EOF" ("For="let comment of Comments_array"><h3>{{comment.text}}</h3><span>{{comment.author}}</span></li></ul[ERROR ->]"): CommentsComponent@0:129platform-browser.umd.js:1909
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors:
Unexpected character "EOF" ("For="let comment of Comments_array"><h3>{{comment.text}}</h3><span>{{comment.author}}</span></li></ul[ERROR ->]"): CommentsComponent@0:129platform-browser.umd.js:1900:17

STACKTRACE:platform-browser.umd.js:1900:17

resolvePromise@http://localhost/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:538:32
makeResolver/<@http://localhost/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:515:14
Zone</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://localhost/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:323:20
NgZoneImpl/this.inner<.onInvoke@http://localhost/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:9100:36
Zone</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://localhost/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:322:20
Zone</Zone</Zone.prototype.run@http://localhost/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:216:25
scheduleResolveOrReject/<@http://localhost/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:571:53
Zone</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:356:24
NgZoneImpl/this.inner<.onInvokeTask@http://localhost/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:9091:36
Zone</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:355:24
Zone</Zone</Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:256:29
drainMicroTaskQueue@http://localhost/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:474:26
ZoneTask/this.invoke@http://localhost/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:426:22
platform-browser.umd.js:1900:17

Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Unexpected character "EOF" ("For="let comment of Comments_array"><h3>{{comment.text}}</h3><span>{{comment.author}}</span></li></ul[ERROR ->]"): CommentsComponent@0:129 ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Object { message: "Template parse errors: Unexpected c…", stack: "BaseException$1@http://localhost/no…" }zone.js:461:14

Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors:
Unexpected character "EOF" ("For="let comment of Comments_array"><h3>{{comment.text}}</h3><span>{{comment.author}}</span></li></ul[ERROR ->]"): CommentsComponent@0:129
Stack trace:
resolvePromise@http://localhost/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:538:32
makeResolver/<@http://localhost/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:515:14
Zone</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://localhost/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:323:20
NgZoneImpl/this.inner<.onInvoke@http://localhost/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:9100:36
Zone</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://localhost/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:322:20
Zone</Zone</Zone.prototype.run@http://localhost/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:216:25
scheduleResolveOrReject/<@http://localhost/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:571:53
Zone</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:356:24
NgZoneImpl/this.inner<.onInvokeTask@http://localhost/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:9091:36
Zone</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:355:24
Zone</Zone</Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:256:29
drainMicroTaskQueue@http://localhost/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:474:26
ZoneTask/this.invoke@http://localhost/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:426:22
zone.js:463:10
```

I should change in UTF-8 or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error stacktrace clearly said that its template parsing error, where you had missed to close `ul` tag.

You have to close the `ul` element as Angular 2 check strict HTML parsing while having template inside `html` file.

**template/comments.html**

```
<ul class="comments">
   <li *ngFor="let comment of Comments_array">
     <h3>{{comment.text}}</h3>
     <span>{{comment.author}}</span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: no problem, this is a new for me.. I never got this errors on angular1.

Comment: @GeorgeValentin yes it will not happen with angular 1, but in "Angular 2 check strict HTML parsing" by design & which I personally felt sensible to have it..